# Why/how does the Longest Proper Prefix/Suffix algorithm work?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, prefix, suffix, knuth-morris-pratt

The LPS (Longest Proper Prefix which is also a Suffix) algorithm goes as follows:

```
public static int[] constructLPSArray(String s) {
        int n = s.length();
        int[] arr = new int[n];
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; ) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)) {
                arr[i] = j + 1;
                i++;
                j++;
            } else {
                if (j != 0) {
                    j = arr[j - 1];
                } else {
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

The `if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j))` part looks clear, but the `else` part is unclear.
Why do we do:

```
if (j != 0) {
  j = arr[j - 1];
} else {
  i++;
}
```

More specifically, why does `j = arr[j - 1]` work ? Or why do we even do it? How do we validate the correctness of this step?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say we are parsing an array of characters with `i` and `j` positioned like this:

```
a b a b x x a b a b ...
      ^           ^
      j           i
```

with `arr` holding:

```
0 0 1 2 0 0 1 2 3 4
```

i. e., the length of the longest prefix/suffix of each substring of s of that length until `i`. You can probably guess how that was generated from the rest of the algorithm. Now, if the next character after `i` does not match the next character after `j`,

```
a b a b x x a b a b a ...
        ^           ^
        j           i
```

we don't have to retry the matching, because we know the *longest prefix/suffix of* our previous prefix/suffix! Looking up `arr[j - 1]` yields 2 – so we essentially cached the information that the parts highlighted here

```
A B a b x x a b A B a ...
=== ^           === ^
    j               i
```

are identical, and don't need to be compared again!

Comment: could you explain why time complexity is O(n) not n^2 where n is the length of the string? since 'j' may get decremented in some loop iterations, it seems it could be O(n^2)

Comment: does it need to look up the "longest prefix/suffix of our previous prefix/suffix" that decrements j only once for any i? wondering about how it's linear in complexity.

Comment: @JoeBlack
x = # i,j is increased;
y = # j is decreased;
z = # only i is increased;
A = x+y+z = the total runtime of the algorithm
we know x+z < n since i can only be increased at most n times

j = arr[j-1] will always decrease j by some value.
 the worst case would be pretending j = arr[j-1] = j-1.
 so now we know:
  j's intial value is 0
  j is increased x times by 1
  j is decreased y times by 1
  j cannot be negative at any point
  this means that y < x
thus we have:
 the worst case for y = x, y < n
 the worst case for x+z = n
 therefore A = n + n = O(n)

Answer (score -2):

```
  *Here's one more solution*
  int length=str.length();
  int mid=length/2;
  if(length<2){
       System.out.println("-1");
  }
  for(int i=mid;i>=0;i--){
      String prefix=str.substring(0,i);
      String suffix=str.substring(length-i,length);
      if(suffix.equals("") || prefix.equals("")){
            System.out.println("-1");
      }
      if(suffix.equals(prefix)){
          System.out.println(suffix.length());
          break;
      }
      
  }
```