# Fastest algorithm to recursively replace substring

Tags: c++, algorithm, substring, str-replace

I am creating a function which will replace in some string substring (not regex) to another while it is possible. I mean string 'aabbabba' transformed to 'aaaa' when I replace 'ab' to 'a'.

```
'aabbabba' -> 'aababa' -> 'aaaa'
```

I guess it is real to do it by O(n). The base language is c++, but I'm looking for just algorithm. Which is the fastest algorithm to perform this?

Comment: abbaabba: replace ab to a while it is possible -> abaaba -> aaaa

Comment: As far as I can tell, the dupe addresses your question. If it doesn't, please edit your question to be precise about what you're looking for.

Comment: @cigien, I edited.

Comment: Ok, but there is nothing in the question I can see that is not addressed by the duplicate. Have you tried out some of the solutions there?

Comment: @cigien, yes, answers there are not solutions for me, because duplicate asked about "one time" replaceAll, but I need to do it multiple times while index of replaceSubString is not -1. Doing replaceAll the same as there while I said above is very slow to my needs.

Comment: Ok, that seems reasonable. I'll reopen. If you want, you can link to that other solutions, and explain briefly why they don't work for you.

Comment: @ВладимирГоворухин how are you sure it can be done in O(N)?

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity first assume that the letters of the replaced string are distinct.

```
'abcde' -> 'cde'
```

We can iterate through the string and apply these rules:

- If the next character is equal to the next character on the pointer, increase the last pointer.

  - if the last pointer is equal to the length of the replaced string (in this case `5`) replace the string, remove the last pointer and continue from the start of the replaced string.
- Else if the next character is equal to the first character of the replaced string (in this case `a`), create a new pointer.
- Else clear all pointers

Let's go through an example with the string `'xabxababcde'`

```
v
xabxababcde
```

`x`: clear all pointers. pointers:

```
 v
xabxababcde
```

`a`: create a new pointer. pointers: 1

```
  v
xabxababcde
```

`b`: increase the last pointer. pointers: 2

```
   v
xabxababcde
```

`x`: clear all pointers. pointers:

```
    v
xabxababcde
```

`a`: create a new pointer. pointers: 1

```
     v
xabxababcde
```

`b`: increase the last pointer. pointers: 2

```
      v
xabxababcde
```

`a`: create a new pointer. pointers: 2, 1

```
       v
xabxababcde
```

`b`: increase the last pointer. pointers: 2, 2

```
        v
xabxababcde
```

`c`: increase the last pointer. pointers: 2, 3

```
         v
xabxababcde
```

`d`: increase the last pointer. pointers: 2, 4

```
          v
xabxababcde
```

`e`: increase the last pointer. pointers: 2, 5

At this point, we replace `abcde` with `cde` and remove the last pointer

```
      v
xabxabcde
```

`c`: increase the last pointer. pointers: 3

```
       v
xabxabcde
```

`d`: increase the last pointer. pointers: 4

```
        v
xabxabcde
```

`e`: increase the last pointer. pointers: 5

And replace again

```
xabxcde
```

And we are done! This algorithm works for distinct elements in the replaced string. To upgrade our algorithm, we need to change the third rule to

- move the pointer to LPS[pointer] and check that location.

LPS array is an array that its nth element contains the length of the longest proper prefix that is also a suffix for the replaced string 1 to n. For clarity, you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60853582/why-how-does-the-longest-proper-prefix-suffix-algorithm-work)